# Migrate to nifi standalone from HDF cluster

Tags: apache-nifi

I'll comment on the problem i'm having.

In the company where I work, they decided a few years ago to implement nifi.
The problem with this is that they implemented the complete HDF solution, something really unnecessary to use only nifi.
With luck the Ambari interface is used to restart the service

I am currently in the process of migrating this nifi that consists of 3 clustered nodes (something also unnecessary since only small tasks are performed and resources are wasted) to a dockerized nifi standalone.

This process was done previously with a nifi with a smaller flow successfully.
The procedure that was carried out was simply to export a template of the flow and to import it, adding in the nifi.properties the correct keys to be able to use the controller services.

I find myself trying to perform this same procedure without success.
The flow is imported correctly but I can not visualize the controllers services that I have loaded by adding the correct key to the nifi.properties.

Try extracting the key from the controller services for load manually that appears as "sensitive value" but I could not do it.

As 2nd option copy the flow.xml.gz of the server to be migrated, edit some fields with a text editor (such as file paths, drivers, etc) and apparently I'm better with this;
I had several errors, among which I had to add the drivers (jdbc, hive, etc). I'm correcting small problems little by little.

Is there really any correct way to migrate this?
Because for more than correctly entering the password in the nifi.properties file, I can not see the controller services? Does HDF have any other configuration files?

As an extra data, the version of dockerized nifi used is 1.2.0, the version of nifi that currently has HDF is 1.1.0. Apparently there are no major changes that could affect.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The sensitive properties in the `flow.xml.gz` file are encrypted with a key derived from `nifi.sensitive.props.key` entry in `nifi.properties`. If this value is itself encrypted (i.e. it is of the form `abcdef...||abcdef...`), you will also need to copy the `nifi.bootstrap.sensitive.key` value from `bootstrap.conf`. With those two values (and using the same algorithm for KDF and encryption as specified in `nifi.sensitive.props.algorithm` in `nifi.properties`), your new NiFi instance should be able to decrypt the sensitive *processor* properties that are embedded in an encrypted form in `flow.xml.gz`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help
I did not know this about the master key in the bootstrap.conf file

I have done the following:
- Export from the original nifi the flow, and import it into the new nifi.
- Edit indicating the keys in the nifi.properties and bootstrap.conf
- The service does not start, the logs announce the following

> 2019-06-06 17:28:21,807 INFO [main] o.a.n.b.NotificationServiceManager Successfully loaded the following 0 services: []
>   2019-06-06 17:28:21,809 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi Registered no Notification Services for Notification Type NIFI_STARTED
>   2019-06-06 17:28:21,809 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi Registered no Notification Services for Notification Type NIFI_STOPPED
>   2019-06-06 17:28:21,809 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi Registered no Notification Services for Notification Type NIFI_DIED
>   2019-06-06 17:28:21,829 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Starting Apache NiFi...
>   2019-06-06 17:28:21,829 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Working Directory: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0
>   2019-06-06 17:28:21,829 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Command: /docker-java-home/bin/java -classpath /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./conf:/opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./lib/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar:/opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./lib/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:/opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar:/opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./lib/nifi-api-1.2.0.jar:/opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./lib/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:/opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./lib/nifi-framework-api-1.2.0.jar:/opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar:/opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./lib/nifi-properties-1.2.0.jar:/opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./lib/jetty-schemas-3.1.jar:/opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./lib/nifi-runtime-1.2.0.jar:/opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./lib/nifi-nar-utils-1.2.0.jar:/opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./lib/logback-core-1.2.3.jar -Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.disablejsr199=true -Xmx512m -Xms512m -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom -Dsun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseG1GC -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=sun.net.www.protocol -Dnifi.properties.file.path=/opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./conf/nifi.properties -Dnifi.bootstrap.listen.port=40303 -Dapp=NiFi -Dorg.apache.nifi.bootstrap.config.log.dir=/opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/logs org.apache.nifi.NiFi -K /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./conf/sensitive.key 
>   2019-06-06 17:28:21,912 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Launched Apache NiFi with Process ID 35
>   2019-06-06 17:28:22,814 INFO [NiFi Bootstrap Command Listener] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi Apache NiFi now running and listening for Bootstrap requests on port 35155
>   2019-06-06 17:28:41,948 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr Failed to start web server: org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException
>   2019-06-06 17:28:41,949 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr Shutting down...
>   2019-06-06 17:28:42,922 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi NiFi never started. Will not restart NiFi

- After this it seems the service keeps restarting so replace the nifi-framework-nar file with version 1.1.0 so that it does not have the correct jasypt library. (Remember with i having migrate nifi 1.1 to 1.2)
- Nifi keeps restarting announcing the following error.

> 2019-06-06 18:25:18,143 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Launching NiFi...
>   2019-06-06 18:25:18,208 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Now overwriting file in /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./conf/sensitive.key
>   2019-06-06 18:25:18,209 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Overwriting key material with pad: c957a7de1ce10bf7a2c1b8cc8907df203e13bfb497e75b81e6fcd8cfbcae449d
>   2019-06-06 18:25:18,209 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Removing/unlinking file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./conf/sensitive.key
>   2019-06-06 18:25:18,209 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Read property protection key from key file provided by bootstrap process
>   2019-06-06 18:25:18,405 INFO [main] o.a.nifi.properties.NiFiPropertiesLoader Determined default nifi.properties path to be '/opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./conf/nifi.properties'
>   2019-06-06 18:25:18,411 INFO [main] o.a.nifi.properties.NiFiPropertiesLoader Loaded 124 properties from /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./conf/nifi.properties
>   2019-06-06 18:25:18,597 INFO [main] o.a.n.properties.ProtectedNiFiProperties There are 1 protected properties of 5 sensitive properties (100%)
>   2019-06-06 18:25:18,604 INFO [main] o.a.n.p.AESSensitivePropertyProvider AES Sensitive Property Provider decrypted a sensitive value successfully
>   2019-06-06 18:25:18,605 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Loaded 123 properties
>   2019-06-06 18:25:18,614 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.BootstrapListener Started Bootstrap Listener, Listening for incoming requests on port 34369
>   2019-06-06 18:25:18,696 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.BootstrapListener Successfully initiated communication with Bootstrap
>   2019-06-06 18:25:18,718 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarUnpacker Expanding 71 NAR files with all processors...
>   2019-06-06 18:25:22,910 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarUnpacker NAR loading process took 4192250200 nanoseconds.
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,177 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-jetty-bundle-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-jetty-bundle-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,186 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/framework/nifi-framework-nar-1.1.0.2.1.0.0-165.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/framework/nifi-framework-nar-1.1.0.2.1.0.0-165.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,188 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-ldap-iaa-providers-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-ldap-iaa-providers-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,193 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-gcp-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-gcp-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,194 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-kerberos-iaa-providers-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-kerberos-iaa-providers-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,195 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-standard-services-api-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-standard-services-api-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,196 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-hl7-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-hl7-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,197 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-datadog-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-datadog-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,198 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-solr-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-solr-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,199 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-websocket-services-api-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-websocket-services-api-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,201 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-ccda-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-ccda-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,202 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-amqp-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-amqp-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,207 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-aws-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-aws-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,207 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-dbcp-service-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-dbcp-service-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,209 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-email-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-email-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,210 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-cassandra-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-cassandra-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,211 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-registry-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-registry-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,212 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-kafka-0-10-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-kafka-0-10-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,212 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-kafka-0-9-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-kafka-0-9-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,215 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-media-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-media-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,216 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-websocket-processors-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-websocket-processors-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,217 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-avro-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-avro-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,218 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-scripting-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-scripting-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,218 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-ssl-context-service-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-ssl-context-service-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,218 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-couchbase-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-couchbase-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,219 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-social-media-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-social-media-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,220 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-kafka-0-8-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-kafka-0-8-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,220 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-stateful-analysis-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-stateful-analysis-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,221 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-site-to-site-reporting-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-site-to-site-reporting-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,222 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-poi-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-poi-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,223 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-tcp-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-tcp-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,223 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-mqtt-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-mqtt-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,224 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-enrich-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-enrich-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,226 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-hadoop-libraries-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-hadoop-libraries-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,227 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-html-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-html-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,227 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-evtx-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-evtx-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,229 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-elasticsearch-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-elasticsearch-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,229 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-snmp-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-snmp-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,230 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-websocket-services-jetty-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-websocket-services-jetty-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,232 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-flume-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-flume-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,232 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-update-attribute-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-update-attribute-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,233 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-cybersecurity-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-cybersecurity-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,233 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-spring-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-spring-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,234 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-azure-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-azure-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,235 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-kite-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-kite-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,236 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-distributed-cache-services-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-distributed-cache-services-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,236 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-ignite-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-ignite-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,237 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-windows-event-log-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-windows-event-log-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,237 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-lumberjack-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-lumberjack-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,237 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-beats-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-beats-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,238 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-http-context-map-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-http-context-map-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,240 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-standard-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-standard-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,241 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-elasticsearch-5-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-elasticsearch-5-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,241 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-riemann-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-riemann-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,242 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-slack-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-slack-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,242 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-hwx-schema-registry-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-hwx-schema-registry-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,243 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-hive-services-api-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-hive-services-api-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,243 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-provenance-repository-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-provenance-repository-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,243 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-mongodb-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-mongodb-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,244 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-splunk-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-splunk-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,244 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-language-translation-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-language-translation-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,245 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-record-serialization-services-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-record-serialization-services-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,246 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-ambari-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-ambari-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,246 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-jms-cf-service-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-jms-cf-service-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,247 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-cdc-mysql-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-cdc-mysql-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,247 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-hbase-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-hbase-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,249 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-hbase_1_1_2-client-service-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-hbase_1_1_2-client-service-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,250 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-hadoop-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-hadoop-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,251 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-parquet-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-parquet-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,251 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-jms-processors-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-jms-processors-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,254 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.2.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-hive-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/nifi-hive-nar-1.2.0.nar-unpacked]
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,323 ERROR [main] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Failure to launch NiFi due to java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.(org.apache.nifi.util.NiFiProperties, java.util.Set)
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,324 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Initiating shutdown of Jetty web server...
>   2019-06-06 18:25:23,325 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Jetty web server shutdown completed (nicely or otherwise).

- Delete the folder of the flowfiles but it still does not start.
- I did the test of using the folder lib of my nifi 1.1 and the error is the following one: Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi

Where are the files specified to be used in nifi?
Apparently for more than amount the flow in the right way, the operation of the processors continues to depend on the files nar with the libraries belonging to its version.

Thanks!